# File Handling used for saving files in a recursive manner

Tags: java, iteration, filenames, file-handling

I have my code generating two files with rewritable data. I need a code that continues generating the files with **recursive file names** and should **keep all the previous files** as well .

In the below code, every time i have to update my file, I have to hard code it and copy it into a new file.

I want a recursive function that saves the file, named numerically in an order(Ascending), while keeping the data in my previous file as well, everytime i run the code.

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {

```
        createFileUsingFileClass();
        copyFileVersion();
        fileChecker();
        String data_2 = "This is the new data written in your file";
        writeUsingFileWriter(data_2);
        copyFileInCode(data_2);


    }
    private static void createFileUsingFileClass() throws IOException
    {

          File file = new File("C:\\Users\\esunrsa\\Documents\\file.txt");

          //Create the file
          if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
          }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

          //Write Content
          FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
          String data_1 = " Initial data";
          writer.write(data_1);
          writer.close();
    }


    private static void copyFileVersion() {
          FileInputStream ins = null;
            FileOutputStream outs = null;
            try {
               File infile =new File("C:\\Users\\esunrsa\\Documents\\file.txt");
               File outfile =new File("C:\\Users\\esunrsa\\Documents\\file_01.txt");
               ins = new FileInputStream(infile);
               outs = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
               byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
               int length;

               while ((length = ins.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                  outs.write(buffer, 0, length);
               } 
               ins.close();
               outs.close();
               System.out.println("File created successfully!!");
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
               ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private static void fileChecker() {
         File f = new File("C:\\Users\\esunrsa\\Documents\\sunrita.txt");

          if(f.exists()){
              System.out.println("File existed");
          }else{
              System.out.println("File  doesnt exist");
              System.exit(0); 
              //System.out.println("File not found!");
          }
    }


    private static void writeUsingFileWriter(String data_2) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\esunrsa\\Documents\\file.txt");
        FileWriter fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileWriter(file);
            fr.write(data_2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //close resources
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
    private static void copyFileInCode(String filename) {
        FileInputStream ins = null;
        FileOutputStream outs = null;
        try {
           File infile =new File("C:\\Users\\esunrsa\\Documents\\file.txt");
        File outfile =new File("C:\\Users\\esunrsa\\Documents\\file_02.txt");

           ins = new FileInputStream(infile);
           outs = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           int length;

           while ((length = ins.read(buffer)) > 0) {
              outs.write(buffer, 0, length);
           } 
           ins.close();
           outs.close();
           System.out.println("File created successfully!!");
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

}

Comment: I don't think you really mean "recursive". But your question isn't totally clear. Do you just need a scheme to generate, continually, new file names? If so, then pick a reasonable naming convention. For example, use a common base name and append the current date or date and time. For example `foo201806051020` and `foo201806051021`, etc. You can keep previous files by not deleting them.

Comment: Please provide some examples of the file names.

Comment: @lurker i am looking at a simple method that can rename all the files I am copying my previous data to, that's all

Comment: Just generate "GNUs-Not-Unix" appended with some random integer for file names, and they'll all be recursive!

Comment: Don't add code to comments. Please edit your question (see the "edit" link below the question) and add your code, properly formatted, there. Then it will be easier for people to see.

Comment: In your commented example, you just want to keep bumping `01` in `file_01.txt`? Just define a string for the file name and use the Java string functions to make whatever string you wish using whatever number scheme you wish, then use that string in your `FIle outfile = new File(fileName);` statement.